# Objective-C EXC-BAD-ACCESS - resolving without ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

For reference I'm using Xcode 11.3

I've got an issue with an object that has been released and it's causing EXC BAD ACCESS.
The good news is that I know exactly what the object is.
What I don't know is how to solve for it.

Here's the code where the crash occurs...

```
- (void)didSendPTPCommand:(NSData*)command inData:(NSData*)data response:(NSData*)response error:(NSError*)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), data, response, error);

    PTPOperationRequest*  ptpRequest  = (__bridge PTPOperationRequest*)contextInfo;
    PTPOperationResponse* ptpResponse = NULL;

    if ( ptpRequest )
```

The crash is on:

```
PTPOperationRequest*  ptpRequest  = (__bridge PTPOperationRequest*)contextInfo;
```

This code is being called out of this code:

```
            ptpData       = NULL;
            PTPOperationRequest*  request       = [[PTPOperationRequest alloc] init];
            request.operationCode       = PTPOperationCodeInitiateCapture;
            request.numberOfParameters  = 0;
            commandBuffer               = request.commandBuffer;

            [camera requestSendPTPCommand:commandBuffer
                                  outData:NULL
                      sendCommandDelegate:self
                   didSendCommandSelector:@selector(didSendPTPCommand:inData:response:error:contextInfo:)
                              contextInfo:(__bridge void * _Nullable)(request)];
```

where of curse I'm trying to pass "request".
A long time ago I'd have managed this with retain/release - not any more. What do I do now?

- David

Answer (score 0):

I think I now have the solution.

```
__bridge_retained
```

So the following code is changed thus:

```
    [camera requestSendPTPCommand:commandBuffer
                          outData:NULL
              sendCommandDelegate:self
           didSendCommandSelector:@selector(didSendPTPCommand:inData:response:error:contextInfo:)
                      contextInfo:(__bridge_retained void * _Nullable)(request)];
```

I have tested and it's working.

- David

Comment: You should think about memory leaks occurring there: request is retained and doesn't released anywhere. What is `requestSendPTPCommand:commandBuffer`? May be you can change it to more modern way with blocks instead of selector with context info?

Comment: I ended up using CFBridgingRetain and CFBridgingRelease. These are used for the contextInfo passed in, and released in didSendPTPCommand:inData:response:error:contextInfo: - I think the solution is tidy and controlled.

Comment: It's better than before, but what if `didSendPTPCommand:inData:response:error:contextInfo` will never be called?

Comment: Agree that could be an issue. Although I don't think there is a situation where it will not be called. The implication is that it is called on Success or Failure. The documentation does not confirm or deny.